# Как запретить вводить определенные числа в EditText?

Tags: java, android-studio

Допустим, что бы нельзя было вводить числа, например, от 107
Или наоборот - до 0 нельзя, а потом можно.

Comment: как вы себе это видите? вот я нажал 1, но это меньше 107 и значит нельзя? как набрать 107 в этом случае?

Answer (score -1):

Если нужно запретить ввод определённых символов, то вам поможет это:

```
EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
editText.setOnKeyListener((v, key, e) -> {
// Если нажатый символ в диопазоне от 0 до 9, то editText его проигнорирует
    return key >= KeyEvent.KEYCODE_0 && key <= KeyEvent.KEYCODE_9 ? true : false;
});
```

Если же вам нужно проверять именно числа, тогда можно сделать как-то так:

```
EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
int value = Integer.valueOf(editText.getText().toString());

if (value >= 107) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Число не входит в диопазон", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

И в `activity.xml` у EditText нужно будет указать

```
android:inputType="number"
```